# How to install most recent version of Eclipse via the Terminal

Tags: terminal, yum, eclipse, oracle-linux

I'm new to Linux and have just been given a VM of Oracle Linux to work with. I need to install Eclipse on it and, after a bit of research, discovered that this could most easily be done with the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo yum install eclipse
```

However, I noticed that this installed Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios), rather than the more recent Eclipse 4.3.2 (Kepler). I realize that I can just go to the Eclipse website and download the most recent installation, but I'd like to know how to do this from the command line (as an educational experience, plus if I have to do this again I'd like a quick and simple way to do it). How can I install the most recent version, or any particular version, of Eclipse via the Terminal?

Comment: How did you "realize" this? By checking the version after installation or by checking the version number in `yum`? The version numbers of the different packages listed through yum might be misleading, e.g. when I look at the `eclipse-platform` package, it shows version 4.3

Comment: @ILMostro_7 when I open up Eclipse, the splashscreen says "Eclipse Helios" and the "About Eclipse" version says version 3.6.1

Comment: is the terminal command (even for the older version) still valid? I cannot find it in my yum repository

Answer (score 1):

Distro repositories don't necessarily contain the latest version of something -- that depends on the distro policy.

Your best bet in this case, since it is drop dead simple, is to just install an Eclipse from the website.  Doing this means you have to resolve any prerequisites yourself, but again it is pretty simple in this case: you just need a JRE (or, presuming you are using this for java programming, a JDK).

Beware that installing eclipse this way doesn't put the executable in `$PATH`, but it's inside the top level of the archive download.  Unpack that where ever you want -- e.g., `/opt/eclipse` and:

```
ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

It can figure out where it actually is this way and use whatever other resources it needs from the archive. You could use `$HOME/bin` as the second path if you prefer there (presuming that's in `$PATH`). *Don't* use a path normally used by the distro installer, such as `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I wrote in the original question that I am aware that I can just go to the website and download it, but I would like to know how to do it from the command line to begin with (an educational experience, I guess). Besides, it looks like downloading it manually requires a trip to the Terminal anyway to change `$PATH`, so I might as well install it from the Terminal. Can this be done? You mentioned the distro policy being the bottleneck; can that be updated?

Comment: The reason I gave you this answer is that if the distro repo doesn't have what you want, doing it purely from the command line would be pretty much exactly the same as above, except instead of using a browser you'd do the download with a tool such as `wget` (or as per IlMostro's answer, `git`).  WRT updating the distro policy, no, the policy is set purposefully and for whatever reason, but some distros have alternative repos you can use (dunno about oracle) if you configure them in.  You can also check to see if there's a newer version that's not the default with `yum search eclipse`.

Comment: AFAIK, with Fedora22, the integration of `copr` -- user-provided pkgs/repos ala AUR on arch--is much easier to implement.  Perhaps I could add it to my answer when I get some more time.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 I'm not familar with `copr` (just glanced at the project page), but I still don't see how it can get any easier than just download, unzip, add to path.  E.g., setting up a repo may mean you can then install in one command, but configuring the repo in the first place seems like *more* work, *more* complexity, and perhaps later provides *more* opportunity for problems, errors, maintenance etc.   Certainly adding more repos for yum to check all the time, or potentially get confused by at some/any point, is completely pointless *if there is only one thing in the repo*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Git) on the eclipse website, regarding the use of `git` to clone packages to your local system. For example, execute the following to clone the C-Development-Toolkit:

```
git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
```

You could also try to find a way to get it with `wget`; regardless, keep in mind that you should have a working java development toolkit.

Furthermore, you could create a `eclipse.repo` file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` as per [this example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseSCADA/Installation/RPM) with the EclipseSCADA project. For a general Eclipse environment, maybe try to include the following in that file:

```
[Eclipse]
name=Eclipse Kepler repo
baseurl=http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/yum/
gpgcheck=0
```

---

In Fedora22, `dnf` provides an option for [**copr**](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Copr), Fedora's third-party repository system, which makes it *much* easier for users to install packages not available in the distribution repos.

```
    $ dnf copr
    Mini usage:

copr 
  enable name/project [chroot]
  disable name/project
  list name
  search project

  Examples:
  copr enable rhscl/perl516 epel-6-x86_64
  copr enable ignatenkobrain/ocltoys
  copr disable rhscl/perl516
  copr list ignatenkobrain
  copr search tests
```

Then, to search for eclipse, do:

```
dnf copr search eclipse
...
mbooth/eclipse-luna : This repository provides Eclipse Luna (4.4) for Fedora 20.
                : 
                : Fedora 20 ships with Eclipse Kepler (4.3) so this repository provides builds of Eclipse Luna for those who want the very latest Eclipse on a stable Fedora release.
                : 
                : If you have problems, please contact me directly via email (mbooth@fedoraproject.org) or IRC (mbooth on Freenode channels #fedora-devel #fedora-java and #fedora-uk)
```

Finally, as per the example, enable the name/project and install

```
dnf copr enable mbooth/eclipse-luna
```

**Notice**
At the time of writing this, the repo is set-up for fedora20 and fedora21; so, the user might have to make some changes to the baseurl in `/etc/yum.repos.d/_copr_...` file until the maintainer sorts it out.